# Is it possible to have street 1 as required but not street 2 on a single store?

Tags: magento-enterprise, customer-address

I've a complex registration form on a Magento website, which is on a Magento installation with around 30 sites on it.

For just one store I require the `street 2` to be optional, but on all the other sites it needs to remain required.

Is this possible, and if so how would I go about achieving this?

Comment: Is that a Magento 1 ?

Comment: Yes, enterprise 1.12